# use return from jQuery .text() to get Object value by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, object

I am struggling to get the value of an item inside an Object. If I do it "manually" the console prints the value. When I use what jQuery returned from the markup, it does not work, however.

Why does this not work?
How do I get it to work?

```js
// fill it 
var storefullnames = {};
storefullnames["dsffm"] = "Designstore Frankfurt"; 
storefullnames["dsmch"] = "Designstore München"; 
storefullnames["dsnbg"] = "Designstore Nürnberg";

// get value from markup 
console.log($('#loggedinstore > span').html()); // DSFFM
var storekey = String($('#loggedinstore > span').html().toLowerCase());
console.log(storekey); // dsffm 
console.log(storefullnames["dsffm"]); // Designstore Frankfurt
console.log(storefullnames); // Object { dsffm="Designstore Frankfurt",  dsmch="Designstore München",  dsnbg="Designstore Nürnberg"}

// should print Designstore Frankfurt
console.log(storefullnames[storekey]); // undefined 
console.log(storefullnames.storekey);  // undefined
```

Comment: Please show the HTML as well.

Comment: possibly some leading/trailing white space?

Comment: Are you doing this within any asynchronous code like ajax request?

Comment: @Andreas note the `toLowerCase()`. @OP given what you state there's no reason `console.log(storefullnames[storekey]);` wouldn't work for you. Check the console for errors.

Comment: what prints `console.log(storefullnames.dsffm);`

Comment: @TCHdvlp that is irrelevant and is already shown as `console.log(storefullnames["dsffm"]);`

Comment: `console.log(storefullnames.storekey);` should print undefined, FYI

Comment: @charlietfl ok, I was wondering because I was expecting `console.log(storefullnames);` to display `"dsffm"="Designstore..."` with the quotes arround `"dsffm"` as it's a string. Maybe he should just declare his object in a different way like `storefullnames.dsffm = "Designstore Frankfurt";` and access it like this `console.log(storefullnames.dsffm);`

Comment: You can't use dot notation (obj.prop) with a variable for the prop name. That's the whole point of using bracket notation (obj[propNameAsString]).

Comment: Code [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/tv3r0jso/). Code shown is not the problem if used *"as is"*. Somehow you are probably using `storekey` before it is defined

Comment: Looking fine here http://jsbin.com/vigeho/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: If I remove the last line `console.log(storefullnames.storekey);`, the code works for me.

Comment: yep, same thing here https://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/zrfg3pe7/  @ScottMarcus : thanks for the tips !

Comment: I think this comes back to the HTML. Please post that as well. You could be picking up a space char when getting the value out of .html();